# Jersey Response for Exception not working as Expected

Tags: jersey, jersey-1.0

I am authenticating user with name and password from my database.
If the user name or password is incorrect then I am throwing a custom Exception.

but I am not getting expected status code and response.

I am new to Jersey and web services.

This is my function which creates a response :

```
public static Response error(int Status_code, String Request_status ,String data, String Response_error){
        ResponseBuilder response = new ResponseBuilder();
        response.Status_code = Status_code;
        response.Request_status = Request_status;
        response.data =data;
        response.Response_error = Response_error;

        return Response.status(Status_code).entity(response).build();
    }
```

This is my custom Exception class code :

```
public class InvalidcredentialsException extends WebApplicationException {
     public InvalidcredentialsException(Response response ) {
         super(response);

     }
}
```

This is how I am throwing this exception in my code if credentials are wrong(user name and password) in AuthenticateUser function in my Model.

```
throw new InvalidcredentialsException(ResponseBuilder.error(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode(),"success","","invalid credentials"));
```

When I am checking my API I am getting 204 as response , but I am expecting a JSON with the parameters which I have provided.

I have implemented my API in the following way :

```
@Path("/user")
public class User {

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public void UserAuthentication(UserCredentials user) {


        UserModel userAuthentication = new UserModel();
        userAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(user);


    }
}
```

I have used the following link to create Exception and throw :

[JAX-RS / Jersey how to customize error handling?](http://JAX-RS%20/%20Jersey%20how%20to%20customize%20error%20handling?)

This is my authenticate function :

```
public void AuthenticateUser(UserCredentials user) {
        Database db = new Database();
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String username = user.getUsername();
            String password = user.getPassword();


            con = db.getConnection();

            if (con != null) {

                String selectQuery_UserDetails = "SELECT name,password FROM user WHERE name=? AND password = ?";

                preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery_UserDetails);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
                rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                   throw new InvalidcredentialsException(ResponseBuilder.error(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode(),"success","","invalid credentials"));

                }

            }}catch (SQLException e) {

        } finally {
            db.closeConnection(con);

        }

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume that `userAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(user);` is not throwing an exception. How do you implement it.

Comment: @Meiko :  I have edited my question and posted my AuthenticateUser function also.
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching but not handling the [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html). When an error occurs, while accessing or trying to access the database, the exception is ignored and no error response is created. Maybe the database is not accessible or configured incorrectly. 
You should wrap the exception into a [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) like [`javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/InternalServerErrorException.html) or just remove the catch statement. And you should log the error here or in an [exception mapper](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665), so that you are able to analyze and fix the problem.

I suggest to wrap the exception and log it like that:

```
}catch(SQLException e){
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "db error while authenticate user", e);
    throw new InternalServerErrorException("db error while authenticate user", e);
}
```

Now the runtime exception will be handled by a default [exception mapper](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665), which will generate the error response. Additional the error is logged. In this code I used `java.util.logging` - if necessary adjust it to the logging api you use.

Comment: The exception invalid credentials is being thrown , I have debugged it. It is also calling the super constructor.
Now I am not understanding if my Invalidcredentials is calling super constructor then why I am not getting client response. 
Is it necessary to catch Invalidcredentials because in the link I mentioned above it is written that "Notice, you don't need to declare the exception in a throws clause because WebApplicationException is a runtime Exception. This will return a 401 response to the client.".

Comment: I have also figured out that if I add a catch statement for Invalidcredentials in my authenticate function then after calling super method , it comes to the catch part ,  this means the exception is working corrrectly.

Comment: What I want to achieve is :

1 . if credentials does not match the database record then it must throw my custom exception.

2. after throwing an exception a Response should be created in the format which I want (for which I am using ResponseBuilder).

3. The response which is being created should be given to UserAuthentication function in my API which produces JSON.

4. And finally this JSON as response.

Comment: Hi, to 2) I would implement an "exception mapper" for that. to 3) the concept in jersey is, that the responsible "exception mapper" creates the response... after that it is given to the client, the method `UserAuthentication`  will not be called, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I just Implemented it and it is working as expected.Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @Shivkumar Mallesappa if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.